# To save image without overriding

Tags: magento-1.7, image

I have created custom module with image upload attribute.Its working Good. But when i edit that row in a grid, After entered save button, image path saved as Array. So i cant get an image in grid and also in frontend.I have paste my code here

```
    if($_FILES['fileinputname']['name'] != '') {

try {    
     $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('fileinputname');
     $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
     $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
     $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

     $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').'/foo/';
    // move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'], $path);
     $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['fileinputname']['name']);
     }
     catch (Exception $e) {
     echo 'Error Message: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

I cant find what changes will i make here. Help me guys

**EDIT**

```
 public function saveAction()
{
    Zend_Debug::dump();
    if ($postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

        /// ---START code for save image attribute----
        if($_FILES['fileinputname']['name'] != '') {

try {    
     $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('fileinputname');
     $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
     $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
     $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

     $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').'/foo/';
    // move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'], $path);
     $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['fileinputname']['name']);
     }
     catch (Exception $e) {
     echo 'Error Message: '.$e->getMessage();
}
}


$postData['fileinputname'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'foo/' .$_FILES['fileinputname']['name'];


//$data['popup_image'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'p_gallery/'. $_FILES['popup_image']['name'];

}
// --END---
        $model = Mage::getSingleton('foo_bar/baz');
        $model->setData($postData);

        try {
            $model->save();

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($this->__('The baz has been saved.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');

            return;
        }  
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('An error occurred while saving this baz.'));
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setBazData($postData);
        $this->_redirectReferer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, when the file is not uploaded the field `fielinputname` comes as an `array` through post.  Try this:

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
if($_FILES['fileinputname']['name'] != '') {
    //your upload code here
}
else {
   if (isset($data['fileinputname']['value'])){
      $data['fileinputname'] = $data['fileinputname']['value'];
   }
}
```

If that doesn't work, post the `saveAction` method from your controller in the question, and the way the `$_POST` looks in the same action.

Comment: $postData['fileinputname'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'foo/' .$_FILES['fileinputname']['name'];
 I have tried with this code for save image path to DB

Comment: I have added saveAction method from controller file. please lookout my edit

Comment: @DRAJI. First of all this is wrong: `$postData['fileinputname'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'foo/' .$_FILES['fileinputname']['name'];` What if there is no file uploaded? What if the file is renamed. Second: put this line `Zend_Debug::dump($postData);exit;` right before calling  `$model->save();` and add the result to your question.

Comment: But In first time, its working fine. When i have try to edit only, fileinputname saved as array

Comment: @DRAJI Then see how the POST looks when trying to update. That's what I've been saying in these comments.

Comment: i have tried with "Zend_Debug::dump($postData);exit;" i got "["fileinputname"] => array(1) {
    ["value"] => string(5) "Array"
  }" when i update

Comment: Strange. maybe you should add the `_prepareForm` method from your form to see how the fields look.

Comment: I have used following code for image attribute "$fieldset->addField('fileinputname', 'image', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('File label'),
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'fileinputname',
));".Sorry for asking this. I cant find the issue comes from  where!